# Decode a sentence using a dictionary

Tags: python

First off, I'm new to python and generally inexperienced with programming in general.

My problem is that I cannot convert the entire sentence in one swoop. I tried a `for` loop, but that just ended up in a whole sentence in a's and b's. Is there any efficient way to convert each letter without creating a whole new list displaying the sentence?

I tried a `for` loop and using a `:` to show all values in the list, but the for loop kept converting letters that were already converted and the `:` gave me errors saying I can't use a whole list as my key for the dictionary.

```
sentence = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."
#sentence before conversion
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
new_letters = {}
#dictionary that makes all conversions (basically go 2 letters down the alphabet, a=c, b=d)
for i in range(0, 24):
    new_letters.update({(letters[i]): (letters[i+2])})
    i+=1
    #creates dictionary
new_letters.update({'y':'a', 'z':'b'})
#had to add in y and z because I cannot go 2 letters down from y or z
new_sentence = sentence.replace(letters[], new_letters[letters[]])
#trying to replace certain letters with other letters, using the new_letters dictionary
print(new_letters)
print(new_sentence)
```

And yes, this is from http://www.pythonchallenge.com/index.php :D

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you reduce the amount of code further? In any case, the skill you need to learn is to step through the code in a debugger, so you can inspect its state at each step to find out where things go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of notes - I will try to stay close to your given implementation and use a dictionary as asked. You do not need to explicitly make a list of all the letters of the alphabet, python has it for you.

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
```

secondly, the alphabet is 26 characters long, so the 25th and 26th characters + 2 are no longer valid and you need to wrap around to the beginning of the alphabet using [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). This is using a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

```
shifted = {l: letters[(i + 2) % len(letters)] for i, l in enumerate(letters)}
```

if you want to be explicit

```
shifted = {}
for i, l in enumerate(letters):
     shifted[l] = letters[(i + 2) % len(letters)]
```

then, you want to replace every old letter with its new mapping by iterating over them.

```
sentence = ''.join(shifted.get(c, c) for c in sentence.lower())
```

This works by replacing every character with the desired shift, so long as it is not whitespace, a period or other non shifted characters. `.get` takes an optional second parameter for the default if nothing is found in the dictionary. Please see gmds' answer for a more pythonic implementation. Also, this is called a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)!

Comment: I don't think that's right; if you try it with `sentence = 'abcde'`, you get `'ababa'` because you can modify a character multiple times with such an iterative approach.

Comment: @gmds lol i have no idea why i wrote that as a loop over shifted, it continues to replace all the letters over and over since we mutate while checking.... thanks

Answer (score 3):

So, basically you want to replace every character in a string with that character's equivalent in the alphabet rotated two places back (so `'a'` becomes `'c'`, `'b'` becomes `'d'` and so on).

There are a few ways to do that. As you have noticed, you can't use a naive for loop because you'll convert characters that have already been converted once. Fortunately, Python strings have a `translate` method, which takes a `dict` that maps characters to each other. Therefore, you can just do this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

rotated_lowercase = ascii_lowercase[2:] + ascii_lowercase[:2]
rotated_uppercase = ascii_uppercase[2:] + ascii_uppercase[:2]

translation_table = str.maketrans(ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase, rotated_lowercase + rotated_uppercase)

print('This is a translated string.'.translate(translation_table))
```

Output:

```
Vjku ku c vtcpuncvgf uvtkpi.
```

`ascii_lowercase` is an attribute in the `string` module that contains the entire lowercase alphabet, so you don't have to type it out manually.

`rotated_alphabet` takes the third character onward of the alphabet and adds the first two characters to the end, so you get `'cde...zab'`.

We can then put the two together with `maketrans`, such that `a` maps to `c`, `b` to `d` and so on, just as we want.

Finally, it suffices to call the `translate` method on any string that we want to convert, passing in the translation table (note that the full stop is untouched).

Comment: A small remark, just don't forget to turn the whole sentence in the lower case before translation `s.lower().translate(translation_table)`

Comment: @constt True, I actually neglected that. It would make sense to include both lowercase and uppercase forms of the entire alphabet, I think.